How to filter based on column data for each individual subject for a data set with multiple observations for multiple subjects?
I am quite new to R so apologies if this is obvious but I have been unable to find an answer to this elsewhere, or perhaps I've not found the words to ask the right question!
I have a dataset that describes how patient scores change over time, so each patient has a unique subject ID and then there are multiple observations per patient. I am looking at how the scores change before and after the event "switch", so I have a variable that is timesinceswitch which includes negative and positive variables. When I visualize my data, I can see that I have several patients who either don't have observations before switch or after switch. I want to exclude these patients entirely from the data so I am only seeing patients who have observations both before and after switching.
I have tried filtering and subsets as I have used these functions previously but with those functions I have only used one or two conditions, like filter between 2 values or subset scores that are not =0.
I am struggling with how to get it to apply to each unique subject ID so that it is checking for negative and positive values across the rows that apply to each patient and then including/excluding all rows for that patient based on whether it meets that criteria.
My data frame is called Trajectories



subject_id
timeSinceSwitch




1
-1


1
-.5


1
.5


1
2


2
-1


2
-.5


3
.5


3
2



So in this very crude example, I want a line of code that would exclude all rows pertaining to subject 2 and 3 because neither of them meet my criteria of having time points before and after switching.
I have tried this but it didn't remove anything:
Trajectories %>%
  group_by(subject_id) %>%
  filter(timeSinceSwitch<0 & timeSinceSwitch>0)

I feel like what I'm asking it is just looking at a single observation level which is why it's including everything, rather than considering all observations for one subject ID.
Appreciate any help!

There could be multiple ways to solve this problem. One method would be to use sign function which returns -1 for negative values and +1 for positive values and we ensure that at least we have one of these values in a group.
library(dplyr)

Trajectories %>% 
   filter(all(c(-1, 1) %in% sign(timeSinceSwitch)), .by = subject_id)

#  subject_id timeSinceSwitch
#1          1            -1.0
#2          1            -0.5
#3          1             0.5
#4          1             2.0

Another option that is closer to what you were trying is to use any function.
Trajectories %>%
  filter(any(timeSinceSwitch < 0) && any(timeSinceSwitch > 0), .by = subject_id)


Hmm, these both run without errors but aren't filtering them out of my data. I'm using ggplot to visualize this dataset and the graph hasn't changed. Is there a chance I would need to do something else with my ggplot code or should that not be relevant? When I add in Trajectories <- before the code above it removes some lines from the graph, but not everything I would expect

did you use assignment i.e. <- to retain any change made?; if not then thats whats wrong.
